# rpyc AsyncResultTimeout("result expired")

Tags: python, python-3.x, rpyc

I'm running classic rpyc server. And when I connect to server and perform long running command:

```
rconn = rpyc.classic.connect(host='ip', port='18812')

rsubprocess = rconn.modules.subprocess
rsubprocess.check_output(['my command'], shell=True).decode()
```

I got:

> raise AsyncResultTimeout("result expired") TimeoutError: result
>   expired

I tried to set:

```
rconn._config['timeout'] = 240
```

and

```
rconn.ASYNC_REQUEST_TIMEOUT = 240
```

Answer (score 8):

You need to modify the "sync_request_timeout" configuration e.g:

rconn._config['sync_request_timeout'] = 240  # Set timeout to 240 seconds
rconn._config['sync_request_timeout'] = None # No timeout

Comment: Thanks. Had same issue this fixed it.

Comment: A proper way of doing it than updating a hidden variable is:
```
rconn = rpyc.classic.connect(host='ip', port='18812', config={'sync_request_timeout': 240)
```